# UIAlertAction Background color

Tags: swift, uialertcontroller

I have a problem with an UIAlertController, it doesn't display with a background color correctly... Can you help me?

This is the code:

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Choose qty", message: "", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
let pickerController = PickerQtyController()
alert.setValue(pickerController, forKey: "contentViewController")
// Testing color
alert.view.tintColor=UIColor.blue
let backView = alert.view.subviews.last?.subviews.last
backView?.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
backView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
// Btns
let saveBtn = UIAlertAction(title: "Save", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default) {
    UIAlertAction in
    print("UIAlertController: Saved")
    pickerController.saveNewValueOfPicker()
}
let cancelBtn = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel) {
    UIAlertAction in
    print("UIAlertController: Canceled")
}
alert.addAction(saveBtn)
alert.addAction(cancelBtn)
self.present(alert, animated: true)
```

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Don't misuse a UIAlertController like that. Make a view and present it through a custom view controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is ugly and wrong design. You should create a custom view controller and add your pick controller into it. Change the background to transparent and set the modal presentation style to over current context to display the custom view controller.

```
self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.OverCurrentContext
```